# Suppose that we have a normal operator with all of its eigenvalues equal to 1. Is this operator identity?

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to see if this the following is true.
"Suppose that we have a normal operator with all of its eigenvalues equal to $1$. Is this operator identity?"

I believe that this operator, say $N$, is indeed identity. Because (I am thinking in terms of $2 \times 2$ matrix) its eigenvalues are all $1$, the diagonal entry of this operator must be 1 with an upper triangular (or lower) structure. (from the perspective of solving the root of the characteristic polynomial of this operator). But, since it has to be that $N^*N = NN^* = I$, it cannot be in the form of upper triangular (or lower triangular) and therefore it has to be identity.

How can we prove this in a general case, though? And am I correct in guessing that this operator is identity? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that a normal operator is (unitarily) diagonalizable, so there is a unitary operator $U$ such that
$$
N = U^{\ast}DU
$$
where $D$ is a diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries are precisely the eigen-values of $N$. Now your hypothesis implies that $D$ is the identity matrix, and hence so is $N$.

Answer (score 1):

As an example for when $N$ is **not** normal,  consider the matrix
$\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$.
A unique eigenvalue of 1, with multiplicity 2.